# How to use a test tornado server handler that authenticates a user via a secure cookie

Tags: python, unit-testing, cookies, tornado

How can I write a unit test for a tornado handler that authenticates a user via a secure cookie? Here is the code (and sudo code) for a dummy test that I'd like to make pass. I'm using Tornado 3.1.

```
from tornado.web import  Application, RequestHandler
from tornado.escape import to_unicode, json_decode, json_encode
from tornado.testing import AsyncHTTPTestCase

class MainHandler(RequestHandler):
    """
    Base handler to authenticate user via a secure cookie.
    This is used for an API.
    """
    def get(self):

        user = self.get_secure_cookie('user')

        if user == 'user_email':
            self.write('sucess')
        else:
            self.write('fail')

class UserAPITest(AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def get_app(self):
        self.app = Application([('/', MainHandler)],
                    cookie_secret='asdfasdf')
        return self.app

    def test_user_profile_annoymous(self):
        #SUDO CODE (what should go here?)
        #cookie = make_secure_cookie('user', 'user_email', cookie_secret)
        #headers = {'Cookie':cookie}

        response = self.fetch('/', method='GET', headers=headers)
        self.assertEqual('sucess', to_unicode(response.body) )
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [mock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock):

```
import mock

...

class UserAPITest(AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def get_app(self):
        self.app = Application([('/', MainHandler)],
                    cookie_secret='asdfasdf')
        return self.app

    def test_user_profile_annoymous(self):
        with mock.patch.object(MainHandler, 'get_secure_cookie') as m:
            m.return_value = 'user_email'
            response = self.fetch('/', method='GET')
        self.assertEqual('sucess', to_unicode(response.body) )
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems you may try to use a `create_signed_value` function from `tornado.web` module:

```
from tornado.web import create_signed_value

class UserAPITest(AsyncHTTPTestCase):

    def get_app(self):
         self.app = Application([('/', MainHandler)],
                                cookie_secret='asdfasdf')
         return self.app

    def test_user_profile_annoymous(self):
        cookie_name, cookie_value = 'Cookie', 'value'
        secure_cookie = create_signed_value(
            self.app.settings["cookie_secret"],
            cookie_name,
            cookie_value)
        headers = {'Cookie': '='.join((cookie_name, secure_cookie))}

        response = self.fetch('/', method='GET', headers=headers)
        self.assertEqual('success', response.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import excel through tornado REST API or want to do Unit Test the handler this may be helpful to you.It's working perfectly form my application.
Here I am passing excel through form-data header in REST.

If want to write test cases for other Rest API's using cookies then it may be helpful.

```
import json
import os.path
import requests
import sys
import time
import tornado.testing
import tornado.web
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mock
from http import cookies
from tornado.options import define, options, parse_command_line

from portal.handlers import ListHandler,excelimportHandler   # handlers created in tornado

APP_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))  # root location where your file is existing
sys.path.append(os.path.join(APP_ROOT, '..'))  # joining file with root path

from portal.library.helpers import get_env_conf, read_env_conf  # functionality to get and resd the the environment config file.
os.environ["ASYNC_TEST_TIMEOUT"] = str(60)  # It will wait for the API for response

LIST = '/data/list'
IMPORT_EXCEL = '/import/excel'

class ProxyServerAPITest(tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def __init__(self, *rest):
        self.cookie = cookies.SimpleCookie()
        define("env", default="localtest", help="Environment")
        define("env_conf_path", default="", help="Environment config file path")
        parse_command_line()
        '''
        reading the env config file for unit test cases
        '''
        if options.env_conf_path:
            env_conf_path = options.env_conf_path
            env_conf = read_env_conf(env_conf_path)
        else:
            env_conf = get_env_conf(options.env)
        self.api_engine_address = env_conf.get("api_engine_address")
        self.api_token = env_conf.get("api_token")
        self.api_username = env_conf.get("api_username")
        self.elasticsearch_index = env_conf.get("elasticsearch_index")

        tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase.__init__(self, *rest)

    def get_app(self):

        env = mock.MagicMock(return_value='xyz') # mocking config file

        def get(key):
            """
            whenever in handlers, if these parameters will be called from there config files
            it will take the parameters
            of config file of unit test cases.
            """
            if key == "api_username":
                return self.api_username
            elif key == "api_engine_address":
                return self.api_engine_address
            elif key == 'api_token':
                return self.api_token
            elif key == 'elasticsearch_index':
                return self.elasticsearch_index
        env.get = get
        application = tornado.web.Application(
            [
             (LIST, ListHandler, dict(env_conf=env)),
             (IMPORT_EXCEL, excelimportHandler, dict(env_conf=env)),
             ],
            cookie_secret="cookie-secret")
        return application

    def _update_cookies(self, headers):
        """
        It will take the cookies that will be passed in whole application.
        """
        try:
            sc = headers['Set-Cookie']
            tempcookies = tornado.escape.native_str(sc)
            tempcookies_dict = tempcookies.split('/,')
            self.cookie.update(
                cookies.SimpleCookie(tempcookies_dict[0].split(';')[0] + ';' + tempcookies_dict[1].split(';')[0] + ';' +
                                     tempcookies_dict[2].split(';')[0]))
        except KeyError:
            return

    def fetch(self, url, new_headers=None, *r, **kw):
        """
        This function will set the headers and cookies for the Tornado application
        """
        if 'follow_redirects' not in kw:
            kw['follow_redirects'] = False

        header = {}
        hs = self.cookie.output()
        header['Cookie'] = hs
        if hs != '':
            hs = hs.split('\r\n')
            hs = hs[0].split('-Cookie:')[1] + ";" + hs[1].split('-Cookie:')[1] + ";" + hs[2].split('-Cookie:')[1]
            header['Cookie'] = hs
        if new_headers:
            """
            These headers will be used if we wiil deal with excel file.
            """
            header.update(new_headers)

        resp = tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase.fetch(self, url, headers=header, *r, **kw)
        self._update_cookies(resp.headers)
        return resp
    def find_body_headers_of_excel(self, file_name):
        """
        This function will provide the encrypted form of the excel in body and proper headers
        that to be passed in API to import the excel using REST.
        """
        fpath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), file_name)
        f = open(fpath, 'rb')
        files = {"file": f}
        data = {}

        a = requests.Request(method='POST', url="http://abc/img/test",
                             files=files, data=data)
        prepare = a.prepare()
        content_type = prepare.headers.get('Content-Type')
        body = prepare.body

        headers = {
            "Content-Type": content_type,
        }
        return headers, body
    def test_proxy_api(self):

        headers, body = self.find_body_headers_of_excel('excel.xlsx')
        resp = self.fetch(IMPORT_EXCEL, method='POST', body=body, connect_timeout=1000, request_timeout=1000,
                          new_headers=headers)
        self.assertEqual(200, resp.code)
        resp = self.fetch(LIST, method='GET', connect_timeout=1000, request_timeout=1000)
        self.assertEqual(200, resp.code)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```